# About "Isocolon"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am trying to get a nuance of this rhetorical device "[Isocolon](http://www.softschools.com/examples/literary_terms/isocolon_examples/305/)"
"On the trend, Off the price." Is this simple Isocolon?
And can you give me more examples?

Thank you.

[HotLicks -- added definition link]

Comment: @chaslyfromUK, thanks, it was good one. do you know any longer one that is famous?

Comment: To my ear, these tend to sound like advertising slogans. And in many cases that's where they originate. ["Always a bridesmaid, never the bride"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/always_a_bridesmaid,_never_a_bride) is an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one to me. I suggest the following. They are well known and commonly used in everyday English.

[Cold hands, warm heart.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cold+hands,+warm+heart%20%E2%80%93%20chasly%20from%20UK%201)
John and Jane meet and shake hands. Jane apologizes because she has been out in the cold weather.
*Jane: I'm sorry, my hands are freezing!*
*John: Don't worry! You know what they say, Cold hands, warm heart!*

[Love me, love my dog.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Love+me,+love+my+dog)
*Jill: I wish you'd keep your dog out of the house when I come over.

Jane: Love me, love my dog.*

Jane means that her friend cannot place conditions on their friendship. Jill must accept her as she is.

[Big feet, big socks](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2011105/You-know-say-men-big-feet-Well-try-looking-index-finger-instead.html)
This is a euphemism and I have given the humorous understated version. There is a folk belief (mostly among women) that a man's penis is in proportion to the size of his feet.
*Sally: Your new boyfriend has big feet doesn't he?

Jane: Well, you know what they say. 'Big feet...'*
Both women laugh.

Note: In this case, Jane doesn't complete the saying because it is so well known.

---

P.S.

I can think of *many* such sayings in English. Mostly they are short. I'll see if I can think of some longer ones or maybe someone else will.

**Note**
Rather than document them all, I'll let you look them up. Simply type them into Google.

*The bigger they come the harder they fall.*

*He who laughs last laughs longest.*

Answer (score 0):

The famous "[**veni, vedi, vici**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veni,_vidi,_vici)" attributed to Caesar is a good example of isocolon.

Other examples:

- Little children, little troubles, big children, big troubles
- first/last in, first out
- lucky at cards, unlucky in love
- Learn from yesterday, live for today, hope for tomorrow (*Einstein*)

I cannot resist mentionning this French (sexist?) one, including a rhyme:

- femme au volant, mort au tournant (woman at the wheel, death at the bend)

Comment: That is Isocolon also Tricolon, and Alliteration. Is it true?

Comment: @teizoartjewelry - both are true for "veni ,vedi, vici": *Tricolon* because  the 3 parts are equivalent in structure, length and rhythm. *Alliteration* because of the repated sounds, i.e. the first conson and last vowel.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best isocolonists was good old [Winnie](https://books.google.com/books?id=5ZVbCNmxjkwC&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=let+us+to+the+task,+to+the+battle,+to+the+toil--each+to+our+part,+each+to+our+station.+Fill+the+armies,+rule+the+air,+pour+out+the+munitions,+strangle&source=bl&ots=dO5nR64Lk2&sig=DNwWR0U3wHogpB1C22jcAhfNR48&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDsQ6AEwCWoVChMIwtDmt6TmyAIVBhkeCh17tQrv#v=onepage&q=let%20us%20to%20the%20task%2C%20to%20the%20battle%2C%20to%20the%20toil--each%20to%20our%20part%2C%20each%20to%20our%20station.%20Fill%20the%20armies%2C%20rule%20the%20air%2C%20pour%20out%20the%20munitions%2C%20strangle&f=false):

> let us to the task, to the battle, to the toil--each to our part, each
>   to our station. Fill the armies, rule the air, pour out the munitions,
>   strangle the U-boats, sweep the mines, plow the land, build the ships,
>   guard the streets, succor the wounded, uplift the downcast, and honor
>   the brave.

One wonders if the guy was even capable of speaking *without* using isocolons.

Comment: Yes indeed, perhaps the best known excerpt from  his speeches is,  "*We shall fight on the beaches, we shall fight on the landing grounds, we shall fight in the fields and in the streets, we shall fight in the hills; we shall never surrender.*" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_shall_fight_on_the_beaches